# AWS Lambda: No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a lambda function that download 2 files from S3 - each 10 GB.
I am only able to write to `/tmp` folder, and there is a limit for the `/tmp` folder of 500MB, so I get `No space left on device`.

Is there a way to download those files via lambda?
Or if not via lambda, what is the preferred option (is serverless is option?!)?

Comment: If you have more that 20GB memory, you can use in-memory files.

Comment: @majidhajibaba what do you mean by "in-memory files"? EBS?

Comment: Now you can use EFS with Lambda

Comment: Take a look at [using EFS with Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-efs-for-aws-lambda-in-your-serverless-applications/)

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a great job for Lambda.

I would use a service like Data pipeline and write a custom job or if it is simple enough an EC2 with a userdata script that when the task completes the instance terminates.